# Android SQLite Table out of range

Tags: android, sqlite, range

When I tried to insert 5 values into my SQLite Database, it says as follows in the LogCat:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table student has 3 columns but 5 values were   supplied (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO student VALUES('csd13','asdasd','12316456','23','12313');
```

And this is my table creation code.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student(rollno VARCHAR, name VARCHAR, phone VARCHAR, age VARCHAR, city VARCHAR);");
```

As you can see, I have initialized 5 fields in the table but why am I not allowed to put in 5 values and it says has ONLY 3 columns.

My insert query is as follow:

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO student VALUES('"+editRollno.getText()+"','"+editName.getText()+ "','"+editPhone.getText()+"','"+editAge.getText()+"','"+editCity.getText()+"');");
```

Comment: show your insert query in code

Comment: Try using the full syntax: `INSERT INTO student (rollno, name, phone, age, city) VALUES  ('csd13', 'asdasd', '12316456', '23', '12313')`

Comment: Updated with Insert Query codes

Comment: Extract your query to String variable and try to Log it, using Log.d(Tag, "message here"); method

Comment: Are you using `SQLiteOpenHelper`?

Comment: Nope, I'm using `SQLiteDatabase`

Comment: hey first uninstall your app properly or clear data of your app than try to run this edited version and also for your information you should use TEXT instead of varchar as sqlite having datatype of text not varchar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because I have FIRST initialized the same table name with 3 fields, and then I edited it into 5. So Basically, change the name of the table OR delete the table from the database in Eclipse.